# R: GLMNET odd behavior when model is reran

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I am trying to use LASSO for variable selection, and attempted the implementation in R using the `glmnet` package. This is the code I wrote so far:

```
 set.seed(1)
 library(glmnet)
 return =  matrix(ret.ff.zoo[which(index(ret.ff.zoo) == beta.df$date[1]),])
 data = matrix(unlist(beta.df[which(beta.df$date == beta.df$date[1]),][,-1]), ncol = num.factors)
 dimnames(data)[[2]] <- names(beta.df)[-1]
 model <- cv.glmnet(data, return, standardize = TRUE)
 coef(model)
```

This is what I obtain when I run it the first time:

```
 > coef(model)
 15 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
 (Intercept) 0.009159452
 VAL         .          
 EQ          .          
 EFF         .          
 SIZE        0.018479078
 MOM         .          
 FSCR        .          
 MSCR        .          
 SY          .          
 URP         .          
 UMP         .          
 UNIF        .          
 OIL         .          
 DEI         .          
 PROD        .
```

BUT, this is what I obtain when I run the SAME code once more:

```
 > coef(model)
 15 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
 (Intercept) 0.008031915
 VAL         .          
 EQ          .          
 EFF         .          
 SIZE        0.021250778
 MOM         .          
 FSCR        .          
 MSCR        .          
 SY          .          
 URP         .          
 UMP         .          
 UNIF        .          
 OIL         .          
 DEI         .          
 PROD        .
```

I am not sure why the model behaves this way. How would I be able to choose a final model if the coefficients change at every run? Does it use a different tuning parameter $\lambda$ at every run? I thought that `cv.glmnet` uses `model$lambda.1se` by default?!

I have just started learning about this package, and would appreciate any help I can get!

Thank you!

Comment: The model isn't deterministic. Try running `set.seed(1)` before your model fit and see if you get the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I thought that would solve it, but it doesn't..

Comment: @nograpes It works in the sense that the same set of predictors are selected. But the problem is that the coefficients still change at every run...

Comment: Try running the example script in the help page of `cv.glmnet`. You should be able to get the same coefficients twice. Are you sure you are rerunning the `set.seed(1)` before both runs?

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Could you post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model isn't deterministic. Run `set.seed(1)` before your model fit to produce deterministic results.

Comment: Thanks again! Are you very familiar with the use of this package? I would appreciate your insight on another issue I am facing, if that's ok...

Comment: I think you might need to carefully read one of Tibshirani's many papers on regularization. If you have general questions, you can ask them on this site, but make sure that they are reproducible next time. The CrossValidated site might be helpful if you have particular statistical questions. But, questions on any site are generally better received when it is obvious that there is significant effort from the questioner.

Comment: Trust me, I have been working on this issue for weeks, but seem to make no progress. I am in great need of help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to feed the same `nfolds` and `foldid` to both models. Check `help(cv.glmnet)` for more details. This will make the cross-validation is identical and you should get the same model if you run the models on the same data-set.

Answer (score 1):

Just a supplement to the answer of @nograpes. Each time **before** fitting the model, the same seed should be set. In short, one seed is only available for one model. For example,

```
set.seed(1)
model1 = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = 'binomial')
model2 = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = 'binomial')
```

For the code above, the coefficients of model1 and model2 could be different.

```
set.seed(1)
model1 = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = 'binomial')
set.seed(1)
model2 = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, family = 'binomial')
```

Only after you set the same seed before fitting the model, the result are exactly the same.